# fragment skip load animation on transaction

Tags: android, listview, fragment, android-animation

as I said,the animation between fragment transaction doesn't occur, because of my heavy load of adapter list view inside it,so,where should I initialize adapter and list view to prevent this problem?I tried to do it in onResume method,and clear onCreatView method,but still no difference.
and another question is which one is better?first preparing list view , and then start transaction animation,or,doing transaction ,show progress bar ,and then prepare list view ?
sorry for bad English
thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what I need,
you should always set your adapter after some second(one or two second usually) in the code,so your transaction animation will be done and next , your list view will be shown(in that tow second you can show a progress bar for better user experience)
Note: this line in your code make it heavy :

```
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

so,you can do what I said by a handler (in runnable , you should call runOnUiThread)